# Modelf Form в Админке Django

Tags: django, django-admin

Добрый день, пытаюсь вывести в админке django поле с ManytoMany, точнее сортировать это поле

так вот

```
class CasinoForm(forms.ModelForm):
class Meta():
    model = Casino
    fields = ['meta_title','meta_description','meta_keywords','title','logo','mini_logo','background','e_wallet','credit_cards','bank_send','e_partomone','pending_period','raiting_total','raiting_admin','external_href','description','support','description_bonus','payment','valuta','games','langs','license','country','sport','rtp']

country = forms.MultipleChoiceField(choices=CasinoCountries.objects.all().values_list('id', 'name_ru').order_by('name_ru'))
```

Делаю выборку по алфавиту Стран, в админке отображается, сохраняет, но не выводит в списке сохраненные(не выводит отмеченные в мультиselecte), помогите пожалуйста

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
class CasinoForm(forms.ModelForm):
    country = forms.MultipleChoiceField(queryset=CasinoCountries.objects.all().values_list('id', 'name_ru').order_by('name_ru'))
    class Meta():
        model = Casino
        fields = ['meta_title','meta_description','meta_keywords','title','logo','mini_logo','background','e_wallet','credit_cards','bank_send','e_partomone','pending_period','raiting_total','raiting_admin','external_href','description','support','description_bonus','payment','valuta','games','langs','license','country','sport','rtp']
```